# X-Event-Key HTTP header not found bitbucket jenkins webhook error

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks, multibranch-pipeline

I have configured a multibranch pipeline with bitbucket repository. Have referred [cloudbees link](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000053051) for the same . Using [Post WebHooks for Bitbucket plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215474/post-webhooks-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview) installed in bitbucket as mentioned in the cloudbees link.

But the multi-branch pipeline builds are not been auto-triggered post commits . Manually scanning works fine.

Also by manually hitting webhook url `https://$JENKINS_URL/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify?server_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org`  returns below error

```
java.lang.Exception: X-Event-Key HTTP header not found
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponses.error(HttpResponses.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.hooks.BitbucketSCMSourcePushHookReceiver.doNotify(BitbucketSCMSourcePushHookReceiver.java:83)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:535)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$9.dispatch(MetaClass.java:456)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:676)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHand
```

I tried implementing different kinds of hooks mechanism available for bitbucket but neither seems to be working . I don't want to use WebHook URL `$JENKINS_URL/git/notifyCommit`

Please help. This is really bugging me .

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post Webhook plugin was not required and our Bitbucket server instance was corrupted. Below were the steps performed that helped it to work

1. Install [Bitbucket Branch Source plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/docs/USER_GUIDE.adoc)
2. Under **Configure System -> Bitbucket Endpoints** , provide **bitbucket server** details with **"Manage Hooks"** enabled and **"WebHook implementation to use"** set to **"Plugin"**
3. Under **bitbucket repository -> settings -> WebHooks**, define hook url as **"https://$JENKINS_URL/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify?server_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org"**

Worked fine post the setup

If using [Bitbucket Server Integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/) plugin with freestyle or maven jobs, enable option "Build when change is pushed to Bitbucket" and webhook should be created automatically with url **http://$JENKINS_URL/bitbucket-server-webhook/trigger** . If not created , manually create it and it should work fine